# Slider with custom ticks (labels and pace)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to make a custom [`Slider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.slider) inside a UWP app, which should look and function somewhat like the scroll in Windows 10 built-in **Photos** application:

[image: example screenshot from Windows 10 Photos app]

There are two main features which exist in this screenshot, yet I couldn't find a way to implement myself:

1. All the positions within the same range in the slider/scrollbar, should have the same tooltip value. In the screenshot example, you can see that all photos within a specific range of the slider (between two ticks) show the same tooltip, which is the name of that month.
2. The gaps between the ticks aren't always the same. In the screenshot example, they rely on the amount of photos taken in each month, relatively to the total amount of photos.

I have found that in WPF, it's quite easy and straight-forward to set custom values for the ticks on a Slider ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-customize-the-ticks-on-a-slider)), but in UWP these attributes seem to be gone. Also, couldn't find anything about it in [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/slider). I did notice there's a UWP control called [TickBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.tickbar), but couldn't find any examples in order to understand if it's relevant for my question.

Am I missing something, or is it really not possible to achieve such UX without making my own fully-custom UI Control?

Comment: @uwe-keim why remove the UWP from the title? it's an important part of the question, I'm not it's clear enough just from the tags.

Comment: [Questions should _not_ include tags in the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Slider control. If you want to make such a control, you would have to do a lot of customization. You might need to make a UserControl. This UserControl nees some basic UWP controls to make it look like the MS Photos app.

For example, you might need an custom ItemsControl(the [StaggeredPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/staggeredpanel) looks very similar) to manage the layout of pictures in the page, and customize the ScrollBar, use two ItemsControls to show the Year/Month on the right side. You also need some label to show the text when you pointer move on the ScrollBar, the label might be the TextBlock control etc. You also might need some [animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/xaml-animation).

Anyway, to make such a control, you need a lot of basic knowledge and do a lot of customization. It's complex. You could submit a **Feature Request** on [WPDev UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Of course I could make my own customization which might turn out to be complex, I just wanted to see if there's an existing UI control or some other way around this, whether official or not :)